# How to get Storage Account containers' role assignments from Access Control tab

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, rbac

i am trying to get all objects from `Access Control` tab from Storage Account container using powershell.

[image]

Using command:

```sh
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName 'devtest' -ResourceName 'sa-name' -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'
```

I am get all objects from:

- Storage Account
- Containers

[image]

As you can see, using this command im getting scopes for `Storage Account` and `Container` in the same call.

I tried using command like:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName 'devtest' -ResourceName 'SA-name' -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' | Where-Object -Property Scope -Like '*containers/container-name'
```

But i am not happy with the results because i am not getting for example `Owner` of this container because it is inheritate from diffrent resource

My question is, how to get `Role Assignments` objects from `IAM` blade for specific container using powershell, CLI or REST API with all objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the RBAC on a specific container by listing all role assignments for the storage account and excluding all containers except for the one you want to see:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName "<your-resource-group-name>" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" -ResourceName "<your-storage-account-name>" | Where-Object { $_.Scope -like '*/containers/<your-container-name>' -or -not ($_.Scope -like '*/storageAccounts*/default/containers/*') }
```